# Second derivative estimates for a subsolution of linear elliptic equation

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

**Definition**. Let $u:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $. A function $u$ is called *semiconvex* if $u=v+w$ for some $v\in C^{1,1}(\Omega)$ and a convex function $w$.

**Note**. Saying that $u$ is semiconvex is equivalent to say that there exists a $\lambda$ such that the function 
$$
z(x)=u(x)+\dfrac{|x|^2}{2\lambda}\text{ is convex}.$$

Consider the elliptic operator of the form $$Lu=a^{ij}D_{ij}u+b^iD_iu$$ and let $L$ be uniformly elliptic.

I want to prove the following statement:

Let $u$ be semiconvex in $\Omega$ and suppose $Lu+f\geq0$ almost everywhere in $\Omega$ for some $f\in L^{n}(\Omega)$. We then have the following:

There exists a positive number $p$, depending only on $n$ and on the constant that define the uniformly ellipticity such that, for any subdomain $\Omega' \subset \subset  \Omega$,
$$ \bigg(\int_{\Omega'} |D^2u|^p\bigg)^{1/p}\leq C(||f||_{L^n},n)$$

where $|D^2u|$ is a norm on the space of matrices.

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: Are you sure this should be expected for subsolutions? The estimate you're asking for is a typical elliptic regularity statement, but as far as I'm aware of you can only control derivatives for solutions, not just sub/super-solutions (as in DeGiorgi-Nash-Moser)